# Microsoft Assure Bot service

Tags: bots, build-automation, azure-automation

Is there any possible way of creating a Assure bot, when O365 email is received to particular persons and can we send a automated call or voice message through MS Teams to alert relevant person.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to avoid mapping Email channel and simply send your email with whatever sender you prefer (SmtpClient, SendGrid...).
your bot can use the channel data property to instruct Office365 to send an email.

Here is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#add-a-bot-to-teams) To create a channel specific functionality.